# Set PW never expire for a list of server

Tags: batch-file, powershell, vbscript

I am looking to set "password never expires" for a local Windows user account, for a list of servers in a text file. So far, I found this command line below, but it only works local on single computer. How can I incorporate this into a VBscript, PowerShell, or batch file to apply on a list of servers in a text file?

```
WMIC USERACCOUNT WHERE "Name='accountname'" SET PasswordExpires=FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should do it:

```
# 1. Define in-line array of servers
$ServerList = @('localhost', 'localhost', 'localhost');
# 2. Define account name
$AccountName = 'test';

# 3. For each server, set the account to expire
foreach ($Server in $ServerList) {
    $Account = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Server -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter "Name = '$AccountName'";
    $Account.PasswordExpires = $false;
    [void] $Account.Put();
}
```

If you want to **import a text file** that contains the server names, you can simply change the first line to this:

```
$ServerList = Get-Content -Path c:\path\to\text\file.txt;
```

An alternative method would be to use `Invoke-Command`, however this requires that you first configure PowerShell Remoting in your environment.

```
# 1. Define in-line array of servers
$ServerList = @('localhost', 'localhost', 'localhost');
# 2. Define the block of code to deploy (a PowerShell ScriptBlock)
$ScriptBlock = {
    $AccountName = 'test';
    $Account = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter "Name = '$AccountName'";
    $Account.PasswordExpires = $false;
    [void] $Account.Put();
};

# 3. Deploy the ScriptBlock to the array of servers
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerList -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock;
```

To configure PowerShell Remoting, run the `Enable-PSRemoting -Force` command on each computer. You can also use Active Directory Group Policy to enable PowerShell Remoting / Windows Remote Management (WinRM).

Answer (score 0):

[`wmic`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx) can be run against remote hosts via the `/node` parameter:

```
wmic /node:HostA,HostB useraccount where "Name='accountname'" ...
```